# Ubuntu - VSFTPD configuration for FTP fails on restart

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ftp, vsftpd

I need to set up a FTP server within my Ubuntu virtual box but im having problems within configuration of the config file within VSFTPD

From online tutorials i keep seeing different options being selected and different reasoning, i just need a simple and secure configuration without enable settings i do not understand.

So far i have selected to use the following options within **/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
Listen=NO
Anonymous_enable=NO
Local_enable=YES
wrtite_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to Toms FTP Server.
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

From my understanding thse options do the following:

listen enables standalone, anonymous denies non verified login, write enable allows to write files, dir message is directory explaining, local time is the time used for dating files, port 20 is self explanatory, xferlog is a log creation/format type?, banner is self explanatory, chroot specifies users are restricted to their directory, users not restricted to their directory are listed within chroot_list.

The problem i am having is i keep seeing reference on tutorials regarding a userlist which will state which users do have access like this:

```
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
```

This does not exist in my file and whenever i try to enter it manually it causes my VSFTPD to fail start up when restarting, i see this in almost every tutorial but it is not contained within my configuration files???

Am i trying to configure this wrong?

What is the minimum requirements for a safe VSFTPD configuration?

Is this user list no-longer supported?

Do i even need this user list?

error code also does not disappear removing these files and restarting again, it completely breaks the service and requires a re installation every single time, the error code is as follows:

```
systemctl status vsftpd.service

● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-04-26 13:58:09 UTC; 14min ago
  Process: 30588 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 30584 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30588 (code=exited, status=2)

Apr 26 13:58:09 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP server...
Apr 26 13:58:09 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
Apr 26 13:58:09 ubuntu systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Apr 26 13:58:09 ubuntu systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vsftpd won't start: "systemd\[1\]: vsftpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181436/vsftpd-wont-start-systemd1-vsftpd-service-main-process-exited-code-exite)

Answer (score 0):

Comment out (or delete) `use_localtime`, and try again.

```
#use_localtime=YES
```

Comment: It would be helpful to OP if you explain why you think this will fix the issue. OP has stated a reason for including it.

Comment: I get a similar issue.
I started with a working config file, then added my settings one by one, until I found which one was the culprit. I cannot explain why this one does not make the vsftpd service not to start.

Answer (score 0):

`listen=NO` means *something else* is handling the listening for incoming network connections - it could be a classic `inetd`, a `xinetd` or a `.socket` unit of `systemd`.

The point is, when configured with `listen=NO`, `vsftpd` assumes that whichever thing started the `vsftpd` process will be immediately handing it an incoming connection, and once that connection ends, `vsftpd` can exit because the thing that started `vsftpd` will be starting a new instance of it for any new connection. If configured like this and started with a simple `systemctl start vsftpd`, then `vsftpd` will expect `systemd` to hand it a network socket attached to the `vsftpd` process's standard input & output.

But since your `vsftpd.service` unit is clearly not configured for this type of socket passing (it would need at least a `StandardInput=socket` line, and a corresponding `vsftpd.socket` unit), the `vsftpd` process gets a standard input & output that are not a single bidirectional network socket, and fails with an "invalid argument" error as a result.

If you are planning to start `vsftpd` with `systemctl start vsftpd.service`, then `vsftpd` will be responsible for listening for incoming FTP connections, and it should be configured with `listen=YES`.

The `userlist_file`, if you choose to use it, should point to a file with a simple list of usernames, one per line. If `userlist_deny=NO`, then the users listed in the file will be *the only ones allowed to login* with FTP. If instead the `userlist_deny=YES` setting is used, then the users listed in the userlist file will *always be rejected*, before even asking for a password.